# vim: restore cursor to original position after <esc> from visual mode

Tags: vim, restore, text-cursor

When I'm in the visual mode and I decide to switch back to normal by pressing `<esc>` then I'd like to have the cursor back on the position where I entered the visual mode. How can it be achieved? E.g. something like:

```
vnoremap <esc> <esc>`<
```

but this will return always only to the beginning of the visual block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use mark. `help mark`

```
nnoremap v m`v
nnoremap V m`V
nnoremap <C-v> m`<C-v>
vnoremap <esc> <esc>``
```

Comment: Using m` instead of mv may make more sense.

Comment: Because the mark "v" is too global. It might be used in other settings/plugins/buffers and raises the risk of a conflict on the namespace.  "`" is more temporary, it affects on "jump-list" and each windows have dedicated lists.  So it can be expected not to be used by others.

Comment: Works great until I start the visual block with a mouse drag. Then the mark is not set. Any idea for this situation?

Comment: Sorry, I've never used mouse in vim.  Did you try `<LeftDrag>` ?